# Converting a query parameters string into a regex expression

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building an app with expressjs and mongoose, 
I'm trying to construct a search endpoint like the specified herein Spotify api
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/

I have a problem figuring out how to convert the given query parameters into a regex to match the required results.
my endpoint looks like this `example.com/search?q=searchText`

Requirements:

- `q=roadhouse blues` is required to match all the results contains roadhouse and blues in its name. ex: matches both “Blues Roadhouse” and “Roadhouse of the Blues”.
- `q="roadhouse blues"` if quotations are provided it has to match the exact word. ex: matches “My Roadhouse Blues” but not “Roadhouse of the Blues”
- `q=roadhouse NOT blues` matches all the results that have roadhouse in its name but not blues.
- `q=roadhouse OR blues` matches all the results that have either roadhouse or blues in their name.
- `q=bob year:2014` matches the results that contain name bob and in the year 2014
- `q=bob year:2014-2020` matches the results that contain name bob and in the year between 2014 and 2020

Comment: Could you please add examples for the last 2? the one with name bob and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the regexes for each of your queries:-

**NOTE**: All regexes use global, multiline and case insensitive modifiers

- `q=roadhouse blues` => `^.*?(?:roadhouse.*?blues|blues.*?roadhouse).*$` -> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/buSigy/1)
- `q="roadhouse blues"` => `^.*?(?:roadhouse blues).*$` -> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/buSigy/2)
- `q=roadhouse NOT blues` => `^(?!.*?blues).*?roadhouse.*$` -> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2r8sI/1)
- `q=roadhouse OR blues` => `^.*?(?:roadhouse|blues).*$` -> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/buSigy/3)
- `q=bob year:2014` => `^.*?bob.*?in the year 2014.*$`-> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2r8sI/4)
- `q=bob year:2014-2020` => `^.*?bob.*?in the year (?:201[4-9]|2020).*$` -> [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2r8sI/3)

Most of these follow a very specific pattern and you should be able to convert queries into these regexes. The last 2 might require some finesse but you've to explain the specific use case of those 2 by examples.

Comment: Thanks, actually this helped alot

Comment: about the last two requirements that involve year, they are required to get the data added to the db in this specific year or range of years. I think it's easier than the rest I'm just going to check if the word year: is in the string I'm going to get the year number and filter the query within this year

Comment: @nasserahmed009 That should be the better approach. Also if you think this answers your question, you should click the tick icon next to the answer. This helps others that may come looking for the same question